# PHP - How do I correctly use a "if(isset() && != NULL) || (isset() && != NULL)" statement?

Tags: php, isset

Hi I am having trouble with the OR operators in this function and I am not sure why?

```
<?php if(isset($value['instagram_id']) && $value['instagram_id'] != NULL) || (isset($value['facebook_id']) && $value['facebook_id'] != NULL) || (isset($value['soundcloud_id']) && $value['soundcloud_id'] != NULL) || (isset($value['twitter_id']) && $value['twitter_id'] != NULL) || (isset($value['youtube_id'])) && $value['youtube_id'] != NULL) { ?>
```

Can someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have a ton of redundancy that is not required. The `isset()` function in php only returns true if the value `is not null or false`. Overly verbose here.

Comment: so just use !=NULL and do away with the isset altogether?

Comment: No. Just use `isset()` and do away with `! = NULL` all together.

Comment: thats a really long if statement o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well....if you want to evaluate all the statement in one condition, then you can reduce your `if` statement to below

```
if(!empty($value['instagram_id']) || !empty($value['facebook_id']) || !empty($value['soundcloud_id']) || !empty($value['twitter_id']) || !empty($value['youtube_id']) ) {

}
```

from the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var
>   == false

`!empty` will also evaluate `null` as `false`

Comment: this is overly too complex and difficult to maintain or debug.

Comment: @fandressouza indeed. but in the OP example, he wanted to do it in one `if` statement, then it is his choice, not ours.

Comment: I am quite new to php as you guys can probably tell from my (now know) overly complex if statement, for future reference for a student of Web Development - what would be the most appropriate method to achieve something like this while still being able to easily maintain and debug the code?

Comment: @Stuart I start out learning from the web, I fail A LOT but then I learn from it. My method is testing and utilize google and SO, they have brilliant answer there and here. try it, if fail, try again, if fail then do some research, if still fail, ask a question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    if((isset($value['instagram_id']) && $value['instagram_id']) ||
    (isset($value['facebook_id']) && $value['facebook_id']) ||
    (isset($value['soundcloud_id']) && $value['soundcloud_id']) ||
    (isset($value['twitter_id']) && $value['twitter_id']) ||
    (isset($value['youtube_id']) && $value['youtube_id'])){
        ... //TODO something
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($value['instagram_id'],  $value['instagram_id'])) {
}
```

This will return true only if all arguments to `isset()` are set and do not contain null.

Comment: You're missing the call to isset?